# How can I forward an email that contains a picture with smtplib?

Tags: email, smtp, smtplib

My code only extracts text types in an email, and forwards the email.

My code:

```
    msg=email.message_from_string(raw_email.decode('utf-8')) #raw_email = fetched[0][1]
    content = ''
    content_type = None
    if msg.is_multipart(): 
        for part in msg.walk(): 
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text': 
                thispart = part.get_payload(decode=True) 
                if isinstance(thispart, bytes): 
                    thispart = thispart.decode()
                content = thispart
                content_type = part.get_content_subtype()
    else:
        if msg.get_content_maintype() == 'text': 
            thispart = msg.get_payload() 
            if isinstance(thispart, bytes):
                thispart = thispart.decode()
            content = thispart
            content_type = msg.get_content_subtype()


    my_mail = email.message.EmailMessage()
    my_mail.set_content(content)
```

But some emails contain pictures, so what I want more is to forward pictures also.

It comes like this:

```
Received: from [127.0.0.1] ()
    by xxxx () with ESMTP id xxxx
    for <xxx@xxx>; Wed, 27 May 2020 18:09:34 +0900
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_1"
X-FireEye: Clean
From: xxxx@xxxx
To: xxx@xxx
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?XXXXX?=
Message-ID: <XXXXXX@XXX>
Date: Wed, 27 May 2020 09:09:34 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0

----_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

CONTENT Link </a><br>URL : <a =href></a><br><br><br>
----_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_1
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html";
 boundary="--_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_3"

----_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

CONTENT Link </a><br>URL : <a =href></a><br><br><br> <img src=3D"cid:unique"/>

----_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_3
Content-Type: image/png; name=image.png
Content-ID: <unique>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.png

LOTS_OF_WIERD_CHARACTERS

----_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_3--

----_NmP-ebdbfeeb1622aae7-Part_1--
```

This mail is multiparted, and there are lots of weird characters which seem to represent an image.

How can I create a multipart email that contains an image, and how can I represent that image with the received weird characters??

Thanks:)